# Проверка существования пользователя на PDO

Tags: pdo, php

Доброе время суток.

Есть таблица users, при регистрации пользователя должна быть проверка, существует ли строчка с таким же содержимым столбца email, как $email
(`$email == $row['email'] = занято, $email !== $row['email'] = свободно`).

Пробовал разными способами, но не получилось. :(

Comment: @misc, рекомендую к прочтению вот [это][1]. Чтобы небыло всяких там "WHERE email = {$email}"


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/research/302421/php-pdo-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85

Comment: @VasyOk, да, уже переделал с плейсхолдерами.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?"); 
$stmt->execute([$email]);
$exists = $res->fetchColumn();
if ($exists)
    echo "email занят!";
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант защищенный от инъекций и с более высоким быстродействием из-за лимита выдачи

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email =:email LIMIT 1)');
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
// exists
}
```